# How to plot vector norms with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider a 2d vector v=(v1, v2). I am trying to plot the values of the pairs (v1, v2) in the case in which the norm1 of the vector (the sum of the absolute values) is equal to 1.

So if norm(v)= abs(v1)+abs(v2)=1, this means that v2 = +/- (1-abs(v1)). I am using ggplot2 to create this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
b1 = seq(-1, 1, 0.01)
fb1 = c(b1, sort(b1, decreasing =TRUE))
lb2 = c(1 - abs(b1), -(1-abs(b1)))
ggplot_data = data.frame(x=fb1, y=lb2)
ggplot(ggplot_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

This is the resulting image. I dont know what am I doing wrong, because the pairs of points to be plotted are defined correctly

Comment: Hm, does `geom_point()` instead of `geom_line()` give you what you want?

Comment: Thank you for posting your data. I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to plot. What do you expect the plot to look like?

Comment: @bouncyball the plot im trying to get is like the one that is formed by using geom_point() instead of geom_line() but with all the dots connected within a line forming the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `geom_path()`.

```
ggplot(ggplot_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_path()
```

***Yielding***

[image]